# Casting shadows based on a specific light?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have two directional lights (light1 and light2) and a cube in my scene. I want cube to cast shadow based on light1 and not based on light2. Is there any way to do that??

Comment: have you tried light1.castShadow = true; light2.castShadow = false; ?

Comment: By this light2 will not cast shadow for any object. I am asking is there any way that material can respond to light 1 but not light2?? I have read about some layer stuff but how to implement that??

Comment: Interesting. Searched a solution for the same problem some time ago but have found only an option to write a custom shader and use or not use lights in shader.

Comment: Specify in your question what you say in the comment please

Answer (score 0):

Use one scene that has cube, one that doesn't. Render shadow from `light1` for scene with cube, and render shadow from `light2` for scene without cube. Implementation should be straightforward.

Comment: Ya this is an alternative. I am already doing that. I thought its a hacky solution thats why I raised a question here.

Comment: You either way need to render two shadow maps. Projection matrices from lights are different and that one cube. It's not "hacky", it's pretty normal I would say.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to render two shadow maps?

Comment: Google for "shadow map atlas" etc.